# How to make an image round using CSS2.1?

Tags: html, css, itext, flying-saucer

I am using [flying-sauccer](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/blob/master/flying-saucer-pdf/pom.xml) version 9. It uses itext version - 2.1.7 (Free license). This iText version uses CSS2.1

I have a requirement to round an image. CSS3 has the border-radius property which works but what shall i do to achieve the same in CSS2.1?

Comment: as far as I'm aware, you don't. in CSS 2.1 there were vendor prefixes for rounding an image, but they all tended to get to the point where everyone agreed `border-radius` should be a thing.

Comment: Do yo mean, -moz-border-radius and similarly for -webkit-border-radius should work? I am not sure, I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @Jhecht - doesn't works. :(

Comment: @sizzler 1. Flying-Saucer doesn't support this. 2. iText 2.1.7 doesn't have a *free license*. Please read [Can iText 2.1.7 or earlier be used commercially?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/can-itext-217-or-earlier-be-used-commercially)

Comment: @Jhecht: Vendor prefixes aren't a part of any CSS standard. CSS does define the *syntax* for vendor prefixes, but actually defining prefixed properties themselves in a *standard* is an oxymoron since the entire point of vendor prefixes is to allow vendors to create *non-standard* properties.

Comment: @BoltClock well I'm not a CSS guru, I just did a quick bit of google. All I know is from the limited knowledge I acquired while using it.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I understand your concern. But, I am using flying-sauccer. why should be i concerned about the internal jars it is using?
You should be bringing this in notice to flying-sauccer for the copyright issues. Please correct me if I understood this wrong.

Comment: Is that project even alive? I thought it had been abandoned a long time ago.

Comment: I can see the latest commits of just 4 or 6 "months ago".
https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer
Not sure about its aliveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image overlapping workaround worked though. CSS applied to both images:

```
img{
    height: 225px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 20%; 
    position: absolute;
}
```

Individual image tags:

```
<img style="width: 227px; height: 227px;z-index: 1;" src="{path to file}/circleImage.png" />
<img src="{path to picture}/picture.jpg" />
```

check the image below(It might not be visible, you may download and see.)

[image: Circle Image with hollow in between]

Hope this helps some one.

Answer (score -2):

use border-radius: 50%; it will exact round of your object.